# Netbeans Platform application using the plugin system

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I am writing a Netbeans Platform application. I want to give this application to the customer while it is in development state and whenever there are updates on a specific module I want to handle it in a way that the customer can use the netbeans plugin updater to update the modules. Therefore I will get a server to host the different modules, also signing the Jars is no problem.

In which way do I have to host the modules and how can I specify which modules are updatable? How do I have to specify/declare the server where the modules are hosted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is quite a bit of documentation out there.

- [How to update NetBeans Platform Application silently?](https://blogs.oracle.com/rechtacek/entry/how_to_update_netbeans_platform)
- [Free Chapter on Update center from The Definitive Guide to NetBeans™ Platform 7](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4302-4102-7_36#page-1)
- [NetBeans How to create Update Center](https://qa.netbeans.org/processes/create-update-center.html)
- [How do I create own update center?](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCreateUpdateCenter)
- [Generating an update center for Netbeans RCP](http://ars-codia.raphaelbauer.com/2009/06/generating-update-center-for-netbeans.html)
- [How to Secure a NetBeans Platform Update Center](http://netbeans.dzone.com/secure-update-center-nb)