# Internal Netbeans Plugin Portal

Tags: netbeans

I need to use Netbeans in an environment where all the dependencies, to include all the plugins used by Netbeans, are pulled from a curated set.  Surprisingly, there is not much available on hosting a netbeans plugin portal, I have found:

- https://github.com/timboudreau/meta-update-center (so far the best option),
- A 10 year old stackoverflow post ([Netbeans Platform application using the plugin system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280293/netbeans-platform-application-using-the-plugin-system)) with broken links,
- And a discussion in the Netbeans mailing list (https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@netbeans.apache.org/msg05664.html) on why this is a bad idea.

The goal is to host a plugin portal internally that Netbeans can use to list available plugins and update from when a new version is approved.  The Tim Boudreau solution appears to be the best option I have been able to find.  Are there any other options available?

Comment: I find your question is a bit confusing. You state _"The goal is to host a plugin portal internally"_, but from the opening sentence it seems that your real concern is _"I need to use Netbeans in an environment where all the dependencies, to include all the plugins used by Netbeans, are pulled from a curated set"_. You don't have to use a NetBeans plugin portal to do that; what is special about your requirements that specifically requires using a plugin portal for your _"curated set"_?

Comment: @skomisa.  Thank you for your comment. The software needs to be able be built and debugged in an environment where there are no dependencies being pulled external from the local network.  In addition, any dependencies need to be vetted and approved for all builds going to production. 

Plugins can be manually installed, but if you want to make updates readily available, the plug-in portal appears to be the solution

Comment: OK, but why opt to host a plugin portal, assuming that you have your _"curated set"_ in your own network directories? By coincidence, [I answered an unrelated question yesterday about installing NetBeans plugins without internet access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73178677/2985643) . Would that approach (i.e. installing NetBeans plugins from some offline directory rather than the internet) satisfy your requirements? If so, you could simply use **Tools > Plugins > Downloaded > Add Plugins** to locally install plugins from your _"curated set"_ folder(s), with no need to host your own portal.